# Nginx redirect to local website without domain name

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm using nginx, supervisord and gunicorn to host a django website.

The website has the following url layout:

```
http://mainsite.website.com/
```

I would like the user to see another django website hosted on the same server when he types the following address:

```
http://mainsite.website.com/othersite
```

In supervisord, I already have a process running for "mainsite" and another process for "othersite".

The only difference between the two sites is that othersite is not exposed to the internet with nginx yet. I know that it would be simpler to use a subdomain but unfortunately I can't because of reasons out of my control.

My question is: Can I redirect the url http://mainsite.website.com/othersite to a website running on the same server, without a dedicated domain? Is it possible to do this by adding a redirect line in the main website nginx config file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a redirect would be the appropriate solution at all here. The simplest thing might be to set nginx to serve both websites, one at `/` and one at `/othersite`.

You don't provide any details of how you're serving the sites, but if it's a fairly standard nginx reverse proxy to gunicorn you could presumably have two `location` directives each with their own proxy and upstream blocks.